# Leaflet: how to select the markers from drop down menu on different layers with clustering

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have many markers on several layers. Markers are located in a quite small area. That's why I'm using MarkerCluster plugin

```
var markerClusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

I have to be able to switch between layers and be able to select a particular marker from drop down list. It's a part of my code to realize it:

```
var selector = L.control({
  position: 'topleft'
});

selector.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mySelector');
  div.innerHTML = '<select id = "marker_select"><option value = "init">(деревни)</option></select>';
  return div;
};

selector.addTo(map);

var marker_select = L.DomUtil.get("marker_select");

var allMarkers = L.layerGroup();

function fillSelect (layer) {
    var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
  optionElement.innerHTML = layer.feature.properties.name;
  optionElement.value = L.stamp(layer);
  marker_select.appendChild(optionElement);
  allMarkers.addLayer(layer);
}

firstMarkerLayer.eachLayer(fillSelect);

map.on ('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
    var selectedLayer = eventLayer.layer;
    marker_select.innerHTML = '<option value = "init">(деревни)</option>';
    selectedLayer.eachLayer(fillSelect);
});

L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'click', function(e) {
  L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
});

L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler (e) {
    if (e.target.value == "init") {
        map.closePopup();
    } else {
        var selected = allMarkers.getLayer(e.target.value);
        if (map.hasLayer(selected)) {
            markerClusterLayer.zoomToShowLayer(selected, function() {
                selected.openPopup();
            })
        }
    }
};

markerClusterLayer.addLayer(allMarkers);

map.addLayer(markerClusterLayer);
```

Unfortunately, the code works incorrect. The markers added to the map twice. First time in the clusters, second time separately. And I can't find the point where it happens. Also I have to switch between groups of base layers and overlays. I.e. I need only two buttons "first" and "second" instead of radio buttons for the base layers and check boxes for the overlays.

Selection for one layer with MarkerCluster plugin works well. Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/atd1pr23/

But I can't organize a selection from different layers with clustering... Here the full broken code:
http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/pgpLg5zw/

Can anybody tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first problem is easy enough to solve: by including `firstMarkerLayer` in the `layers` array of your `map` options, you are telling Leaflet to add that (unclustered) layer to the map. So don't do that. As to the other problems, what is your expected behavior for the layer control? Do you want to switch between all `first` and `second` layers exclusively (i.e. a radio that shows either `firstTileLayer` and `firstMarkerLayer` OR `secondTileLayer` and `secondMarkerLayer`)?

Comment: Yes, when I don't add `firstMarkerLayer` in the `map` options, only the clustered layer remaines on my map. But the selection from the drop down menu works with these non-clustered layers and the layers control works with them. I.e. when I highlight the check box from the layer control, non-clustered `firstMarkerLayer` comes back together with the clustered layer. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/pgpLg5zw/

Comment: Regarding the second question I want to put the markers from the `firstMarkerLayer` into the `firstBaseLayer` and markers from the `secondMarkerLayer` into the `secondBaseLayer`. I need to operate with these pairs (MarkerLayer + BaseLayer). I.e. I need only two buttons. The first button have to turn on the `firstMarkerLayer` and the `firstBaseLayer` two together, second button have to turn on the second pair. By default Leaflet creates separately radio buttons for base layers and check boxes for marker layers. And I can't unite them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an sample for you http://jsfiddle.net/px9LyL87/6/
There is a map with one basemap layer, and two marker cluster layers.

```
// Create marker layers
var markerLayer1 = L.markerClusterGroup({
    id: "markerLayer1"
});
var markerLayer2 = L.markerClusterGroup({
    id: "markerLayer2"
});
```

For the layers control and supply only marker layers.

```
// Add controls to the map
L.control.layers({}, {
    "Marker 1": markerLayer1,
    "Marker 2": markerLayer2
}).addTo(map);
```

If you supply also basemaps layers, there will be radio buttons for them in the control, that's just how it works, you can have only one basemap visible at a time. You can turn on/off your marker layers. Adding and removing the marker layers will cause updating of the select drop down.

```
// Handle map layeradd event
map.on("layeradd", function(e) {
    // Handle only marker layers
    if((e.layer.options.id != "markerLayer1") && (e.layer.options.id != "markerLayer2")) {
    return;
  }

  // For the currently added layer (which is one with markers)
  // get all its layers
  var markers = e.layer.getLayers();

  // Get the dropdown
  var mySelector = $("#mySelector");

  // Add options to the dropdown menu
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    mySelector.append("<option value='" + L.stamp(markers[i]) + "'>" + markers[i].feature.properties.name + "</option>");
  }
});
```

In these handlers I just check if the currently adding/removing layer is the one with markers, and according to it I add or remove items from/to the select dropdown. I hope that, this is what you wanted. Please let me know if not.

Comment: It is almost that I need, but I also need to switch base layers and marker layers together in pairs. I know that I can have only one visible base layer on the map, but I need to change it with the changing of corresponding marker layer. By default Leaflet creates radio buttons for base layers and check boxes for marker layers separately. I need to unite them in the common button. I.e. my purpose is a toggling from the `firstMarkerLayer`+`firstBaseLayer` to the second pair with a pushing to the individual button for the each pair. Is that behavior is possible?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the fiddle, look at it now please, http://jsfiddle.net/px9LyL87/7/ You just need to group one marker layer with one basemap, and second marker layer with second basemap. I hope that's what you need.

Comment: @Anton: Did you take a look at that fiddle?

Comment: Thank you, it works as I need! One more question about design: is there a way to change standart leaflet radio buttons to separate buttons overlapping the map?

Comment: Yes, you can re-style them just with css, or you can create your own control.